# Performance heavily increase when upgrading from 1.5.21 to 1.5.25

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

After one pharma hack attack I had upgraded my site from <strike>1.5.21</strike> 1.5.22 to 25. But after this my shared hosting account was disabled and I saw heavy performance increase in the cpu graph. Previously I was running some 10 sites along with it having more than traffic of 3500/day ( total including my pre-upgraded site = +7000/day).

Now I'm managing the sites in two different hosting accounts.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should now upgrade from 1.5.25 to 1.5.26 as it's the latest version of the Joomla 1.5 series.

Upgrading from Joomla 1.5.21 to .25 would not cause a performance increase in the CPU graph.
It's probably due to the fact you have 5 Joomla sites on each server with a lot of activity.
I would recommend getting a VPS server rather than using 2 shared hosting accounts.

Comment: No I've only two sites in Joomla one with 3-5000 traffic and another 200. Others are in Drupal. But yes performance is heavily increased, no idea why. Thanks I'll update from 1.5.25 to 26 . I mentioned it wrong. I upgraded from v22 to 25 and NOT from 1.5.21

Comment: Drupal...Joomla...they are both CMS's and fairly big ones at that. Shared Hosting Accounts are usually fit for 1 big CMS site with lots of traffic and even then, a site with the amount of traffic you have would be best on a VPS server.

Comment: All those were fairly accommodated in 1 shared hosting for the last many months until I upgraded 1 site from 1.5.21 to 1.5.25 then the cpu usage of this upgraded site zoomed heavily.